# Python code to Convert Text from One Language to another using Microsoft Translate API

Tags: python, python-3.x, translate

I was trying to develop a Multi language Chat application which can convert text from one language to another using Python.

I have tried couple of solutions and I found the Microsoft Bing Translate Api a perfect solution for my requirement.

I am posting this question and answer together since I thought it might help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from translate import Translator

class clsTranslate():

    def translateText(self, strString, strTolang):
        self.strString = strString
        self.strTolang = strTolang
        translator = Translator(to_lang=self.strTolang)
        translation = translator.translate(self.strString)
        return (str(translation))

# Create a Class object and call the Translate function

objTrans=clsTranslate()
strTranslatedText= objTrans.translateText('How are you', 'de')

print(strTranslatedText)
```

Comment: You shouldn't manually call `x.__str__()`; use `str(x)` instead.

Comment: In addition, there's no reason for this to be a class.

Comment: Please make sure you have got Translator installed on your Python environment.

Comment: Run the following command from command line to install Translator, >  pip install translate

Comment: Is translate module in python open source? meaning can we use it for n number of requests/words? @ChikkuJacob

Comment: @Dinesh I think there is a limit of 5000 characters.